# apt コマンド実行時にネットワーク接続がタイムアウトしてしまう

Tags: ubuntu, apt

カフェのネットワークを使って作業をしており、 `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` を実行したのですが、以下エラーが出てしまいます。

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

そこで、

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

をすると良いと聞き、実行したのですが、

```
~$ sudo apt update
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                          
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                  
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease        
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                                  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

のようにエラーが出てしまい、

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

をして、

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

をしても上記のエラーと同様のエラーが出てしまします。
どうすれば改善できるでしょうか？
お願い致します。

Comment: 対象の Ubuntu から外部のネットワークには接続できていますか？また、会社や学校等の LAN 環境でプロキシを使用していたりしませんか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！カフェで作業をしています！
Ubuntuから外部のネットワークに接続できるかどうか試してみます！
ありがとうございます！
セキュリティーの問題ということでしょうか？

Comment: apt はインターネット経由でパッケージ等のデータを受信しますが、エラーでは指定されたアドレスとの通信ができないと出ています。apt だけの問題なのか、そもそも Ubuntu 自体がネットワークに繋がっているのか、問題点の切り分けが必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
試しに、ping www.homes.co.jpを実行したところ、
64 bytes from server-99-84-59-89.nrt20.r.cloudfront.net (99.84.59.89): icmp_seq=1 ttl=237 time=29.1 ms
…
のように表示され、
--- www2.homes.co.jp ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5008ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 12.351/21.282/33.068/7.793 ms
と最後の方に表示されました。Ubuntu自体はネットワークに繋がっているかと考えられます。
aptだけの問題かもしれません。

Comment: もしも WSL2ならば, こんなのが https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777927/apt-get-update-failed-on-wsl2 あるいは [WSL2でUbuntuを動かしたらハマった件（sudo apt-get updateできない）](https://qiita.com/riraosan/items/3b036367d6d9f4e6b52a)

Comment: [oriri](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/43025/oriri)さん、ありがとうございます！！
嬉しい報告なのですが[WSL2でUbuntuを動かしたらハマった件（sudo apt-get updateできない）](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777927/apt-get-update-failed-on-wsl2)の通り、Avastのファイヤーウォール設定を変えると上手くいきました！！
お陰様で無事pipがインストール出来ました！！
[cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)さんもありがとうございました！！！感謝です！！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決しましたので報告させて頂きます。

コメント頂いた、[cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)さん、[oriri](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/43025/oriri)さん、ありがとうございました。
コメントではリンクとページの名称を間違えて打ってしまっていたのですが、正確には、
"[apt-get update failed on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777927/apt-get-update-failed-on-wsl2)の通り"でした。

如何にして「sudo apt-get install python3-pipをしたい。ubuntu: sudo apt update時にエラーが出る」が解消したかを申しますと、[apt-get update failed on WSL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60777927/apt-get-update-failed-on-wsl2)にある通り、当方のPCでアンチウィルスソフトのAvastが働いており、Avastの設定で、プロテクションの設定に行き、該当する「現在のネットワーク」の「設定を表示」に進み、
「このネットワークを信頼していません(パブリック)」から「このネットワークを信頼しています(プライベート)」に変更することで解決致しました。

[image: プロテクションの設定]

無事

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

を実行でき、pipがインストールされました。
[image: インストールされたpip]

ありがとうございました。